# Restler-3: index()-function

Tags: json, indexing, split, restler

I'm playing around with Restler3 (really awesome!) and noticed a problem.
So, the index() function should list all rows of a table, that's correct, right?
I'm doing it that way: index() lists all rows of a table. But the client doesn't support to load an JSON object that's maybe about 50k rows big.

I think you can see the problem: 
I want to split that up in parts of maybe 50 rows. That would mean:

1. Call index()
2. Get number of queries to run (eg. 100rows would result in two queries)
3. Call index(1) and save
4. Call index(2) and save

My question is now: What's the best solution for that splitting? What do you think about my example? Can Restler already do such things?

Thank's for reading. Maybe you know something. Just answer…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem faced by many API's see how twitter, Facebook and all are handling it

Googling about `API pagination` will also help

I suggest you add 2 optional parameters such as `limit` and `offset` and use them in your query

On the api side you may specify limit = 50, and offset=0 and also set the minimum and maximum for limit using a comment such as `{@min 10}{@max 100}` then client wont be able to tax your server with big queries